# Displaying elements of a string array separately with button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting a text from server side and I want to show one word for each button click. Here is my approach:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
            {       
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: "request.php",
                    success: function (response){

                var words = text.match(/\b([a-z]{1,})\b/gi);  //text is an element of json array
                        for (i = 0;  i < 10;  ++i)
                            $("#container").append("<span>"+words[i]+"</span>").hide();
                    }           
                });
            });
```

My function to display words. It doesn't work, just for explaining what I'm trying to do.

```
    $(function() 
    {           
        $("#button").click(function(){
            $("#container span").fadeIn(450);  // shows nothing
        });
    });
```

Jquery selector can't select the spans because they are not at html. Could you advise me a solution?

(When I wrote $("#container").fadeIn(450); it shows all the words.)

Comment: can you provide the JSON response?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more.

Comment: Can you give the text you receive in your browser when you in request.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There two problems with your code;

You're using `.append()` to append `span` elements to `#container` but it returns `#container` jQuery object. So everytime you append a `span` element you call `.hide()` for `#container`. As you can see I changed it a little. You have to create `span` element, hide it and then append it to `#container`, like this;

```
$("<span>"+words[i]+" </span>").hide().appendTo("#container");
```

Second problem is with your `.click()` function. Your selector selects all span elements, there is pseudo selectors for selecting hidden elements or first element etc. Using them together you can select first hidden element like this;

```
$('#container span:hidden:first');
```

And finally implementing these to your code will give us this result;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "request.php",
        success: function(response) {
            var words = text.match(/\b([a-z]{1,})\b/gi); //text is an element of json array
            for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
                $("<span>"+words[i]+" </span>").hide().appendTo("#container");
            }
        }
    });
});

$(function() {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $('#container span:hidden:first').fadeIn(450);
    });
});
```

But of course, if you want to `fadeIn` all of your `span` elements at once you can use your piece of code;

```
$("#container span").fadeIn(450);
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/ELHsE/) is an example of your code.

Comment: It works, thank you. What's the difference between $("<span>"+words[i]+" </span>").hide().appendTo("#container");
and $("#container").append("<span>"+words[i]+"</span>").hide();

Comment: Updated my answer and explained everything.

Comment: Thanks, and one more little question. I'm displaying the spans at different lines, however I styled them inline. What may cause that?

Comment: It's hard to tell anything without seeing your code. You can make a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) case and ask another question for that problem.

Comment: What about CSS, check your span elements with Firebug or Developer Tools and see if it has some other CSS rule (`display: block` or something like that)

Comment: The problem I told is already at your example and there is no css there. Could you take a look to your example, thank you. http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/ELHsE/

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option for you:

```
$('span').hide();
var i = 1;

$("#button").click(function(){
    if (i <= $("#container > span").size()){
        $("#container span:nth-child("+i+")").fadeIn(450);  // shows nothing
        if (i < $("#container > span").size()){
            i++;
        }
        else {
            $(this).attr("disabled", true)
        }
    }    
});
```

See the example here - http://jsfiddle.net/xhMnt/2/

Hope it helps. Alex

Answer (score 1):

[Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8604169/990877) is a pretty solid way of showing the spans one-by-one. How create the spans from your AJAX response depends on the type of data your PHP script is returning. If the response looks like this:

```
[
    "Some",
    "words",
    "via",
    "JSON"
]
```

...it's pretty easy:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "request.php",
    success: function(data, status) {
        var container = $("#container");
        var word;

        for (word in data) {
            $('<span />').append(word).appendTo(container);
        }
    }
});
```

On the other hand, if the response looks like this: "`Some words as plaintext`", you'd have to do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'text',
    url: "request.php",
    success: function(data, status) {
        var container = $("#container");

        var words = data.split(' ');
        var word;

        for (word in words) {
            $('<span />').append(word).appendTo(container);
        }
    }
});
```

Notice I changed the `dataType` to `text`, and I added the variable `words`, which `split()`s the result on the space character.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it

```
$("#container span:eq(" + ($("#container span.active").removeClass("active").fadeOut().index()+1) + ")").addClass("active").fadeIn();
```

see a demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/y7qdV/5/

Answer (score 0):

Declare two vars:

```
var arr = [];
var inc = 0;
```

After the ajax call, store the words to an array:

```
for (i = 0;  i < 10;  ++i)
                        arr.push(words[i]);
                }
```

then:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
  while (inc < arr.length) {
        $("#container").html("<span>"+words[i]+"</span>");
          inc++; 
    });
```

I havent tested this. Hope this helps.